# Modify the current URL with dynamic values in php using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get current URL, modify a couple of string parameters in the URL with dynamic values, and redirect to that modified URL.
I have obtained current URL with `'location.href' : http://dev.azima.com/@mt.everest2017@/page-content/about-us/5`

I tried to replace last two parameters (strings) `'about-us' and '5'` with `$page->slug and $page->id` respectively.
I tried string manipulation methods, but couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Do you want to modify the url in PHP

Comment: @NadirLaskar yes.. I want to edit two parameters and redirect to that URL

Comment: Post some code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL pattern is fixed, it can be achieved in PHP with help of explode/implode functions. Like This:

```
$url = "http://dev.azima.com/@mt.everest2017@/page-content/about-us/5";
$url_arr = explode("//", $url);
$url_arr[count($url_arr) - 1] = $page->id;
$url_arr[count($url_arr) - 2] = $page->slug;

$url = implode("//", url_arr);
header("location:$url");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Let me write what I understood of what you want to do:**

1. User is going to an URL
2. Some code is done in PHP
3. User is redirected to a new URL through Javascript

If there is no user interaction, it is possible without any other step.

But you really need to understand that PHP is a server side language and 
Javascript is a client side language.

You can't pass content from JS to PHP without any AJAX call.

**Solution**

So basically, you will do that

```
<?php
/** YOUR PHP CODE WITH $_GET $_POST RETRIEVALS OR WHATEVER **/
$javascript = '(function() {
   // your redirection
})();';
?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your HTML here

<script>
<?php echo $javascript; ?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To be honest, I would rather consider this type of code which is pure PHP, faster and easier:

```
<?php
/** YOUR PHP CODE WITH $_GET $_POST RETRIEVALS OR WHATEVER **/
if(!empty($redirectIsNeeded)) {
    header('Location: http://foo.bar');
}
?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your HTML here
</body>
</html>
```

You can also consider, if a load is not needed and only want to "display" the right URL in URL bar, using history.pushstate.